# How to make sure that the specified key of an object extends Array?

Tags: typescript

How do I make sure that the specified `keyof` a type extends an array?

For example I have this type:

```
type TestType = {
    arrayKey: Array<number>,
    notArrayKey: number
}
```

And I have this function that will access the specified key of the type:

```
const getKey = <T>(object: T, key: keyof T): Array<any> => {
    return object[key]
}
```

How do I make sure that the only valid input of `key` are `arrayKey` as it extends `Array` and not "`notArrayKey`" which does not extends `Array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Behemoth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73164753/438273) will provide good IntelliSense suggestions for the key if you choose to use the parameter order of `(object, key)`.

More simply, if you reverse the parameters, you can use [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to ensure that the `object` argument conforms to a type having an array value at the `key` argument provided:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUCSYA8gEYBWiAPAFCKIDSqAnoqgB5SpgAmAzoj5QATjDDIANHURlKHLrwEAlVBDjCeVJswmJhqLDwQ5WWMMwDaAXQB8UmwAoA1iwBcjFrrgVVUd7IBKfwoLbStEAG9pfSgQYSRvcl8LF2YrAG4aAF8aGjUwIURExABeSOksYWEsZm13CwBGXQAmXQBmKyl6MAQAQSqausQAcgbmtuGpLMyaNExcfCJZB2HK6tqWSaKKAPTEAHp9mQZcuew8QhIKFZ6wfvXtLcTdg4AqaXpPr++f34A-AE0frIEAAW24UCKwEQUGYAAdUCMIog1oM3IgwGDSKhhNY9rd7mjmO4hKJxHsssNEDABD1IVg+HwYMgwFhSDhEVA4Ig4ZUsOCuMIoTD4Yjhio1BoqAAiAkDDbMaW6fSGYymczWGzDAB00gAKqKBHBoXDhHAEcJYSM5Q9Nij9NTIHBQbzYOzULqvgaESNSWJkFSaRi4PTGczWe6YdzYT7hiqjGATCiNVYdQ5xgAWACsAUQr32QA)

```ts
function getValueInObj <
  Key extends string,
  Obj extends Record<Key, readonly any[]>,
>(key: Key, object: Obj): Obj[Key] {
  return object[key];
}

const obj = {
  arrayKey: [1, 2, 3],
  nonArrayKey: '123',
};

getValueInObj('arrayKey', obj); // OK

getValueInObj('nonArrayKey', obj); /*
                             ~~~
Argument of type '{ arrayKey: number[]; nonArrayKey: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"nonArrayKey", readonly any[]>'.
  Types of property 'nonArrayKey' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[]'.(2345) */
```

---

Expanding on the other answer:

The type mapping can be performed in the generic constraint in order to provide a type parameter name to use in the return type.

In the example below, when the `obj` value is provided as the first argument to the function, the generic type `Obj` becomes the type of that object, and the type parameter `Key` becomes a union of all of its properties which have value types that extend `readonly any[]` (which means an immutable array with elements of any type). This union ends up looking like `'arrayKey' | 'anotherArrayKey'`, so the value provided to `key` has to be one of those strings, or a compiler error diagnostic will be emitted.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUCSYA8gEYBWiAPAFCKJmWoAeUqYAJgM6IBKqEOACcOVAApC4AB1RCoATwDSqeQBpEWMPIB8quomXzELNpx4BrFXGCIA3vvoBtB-QOIYSS-OsMKGnoyOigC6xqzs3IhCqFgcCDhGmvKOwS6uiAD8BmmuAFyIYKgAbrIuwfng5mBwAO5gANyIAPRNiAAqABaoiABEldV1PYgKMoggXKgciF3R-sNdiEW4+IhxqFxgAORQiAC2WFBsQvoAvurpF-QtiKQCWOPdMDvIcOtjYA8c+U+IgiA4U1uGi0w3kMho2gAFHAKAIoPlGOovPlDABKBEUIIqUL2ejRKAgIRIGHkOGOLzBeo0E40GiCMBcHYkxAAXjs+iwQiEWCUKnyjgAjOoAEzqADMwT09E0cCgMwAglyeYZ+ZssJt1JtSBrEJsIJtJfpqmBFdzefJ8psBcKxRrqVSaGhMMtCCQKNCKJrOWbDJtUY1rh9drchClaU7sHhXYwPeRNcbTcqVH6AwAqHKXTMAPxzubzuZoiuQIF27CZNhG3U2PQTSvNPU27h41R2WC4XBgyDAWFIOG6UDgiCknKwpaOiB8ld1PW9SfkQwAPr0ZXLZIn65sAHSQm0AFgArKjEKmmjQgA)

```ts
function getValueInObj <
  Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, any>,
  Key extends keyof {
    [
      K in keyof Obj as Obj[K] extends readonly any[]
        ? K
        : never
    ]: unknown; // The "unknown" type used here as the value doesn't matter
  },            // because it goes unused: it could be any type
>(object: Obj, key: Key): Obj[Key] {
  return object[key];
}

const obj = {
  arrayKey: [1, 2, 3],
  anotherArrayKey: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  nonArrayKey: '123',
};

getValueInObj(obj, 'arrayKey'); // number[]

getValueInObj(obj, 'nonArrayKey'); /*
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Argument of type '"nonArrayKey"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"arrayKey" | "anotherArrayKey"'.(2345) */
```

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks! So it's possible to use a type assertion from key to value with `K in keyof Obj as Obj[K]`?

Comment: @Behemoth Can you clarify? Are you asking about [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the key mapping. If `K in keyof Obj` is the object's key. Then `Obj[K]` must be it's value, no?

Comment: @Behemoth Yes, that's right: `Obj[K]` in the [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) expression refers to the type of the value at the `K` key in `Obj`.

Comment: That's crazy. I didn't know that was possible. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Behemoth No problem. The whole reason I'm on this site is because of how much I value learning and knowledge sharing, and I'm glad that you are feeling stronger in TypeScript after this interaction!

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of making the object type of Record that have the key with the key type of an array. That's genius, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could *filter* the keys of `TestType` by their value with a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). Basically this checks whether the value of a key extends `Array<number>` (`T[K] extends Array<number>`). An example for both keys of `TestType`:

1. Does `TestType.arrayKey` extend `Array<number>`? --> Yes, valid key
2. Does `TestType.notArrayKey` extend `Array<number>`? --> No, not a valid key because it has the type `number`

---

```
type TestType = {
  arrayKey: Array<number>;
  notArrayKey: number;
};

const test = {
  arrayKey: [0],
  notArrayKey: 0
};

const getKey = <T extends object>(
  object: T,
  key: {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<number> ? K : never;
  }[keyof T]
): T[keyof T] => {
  return object[key];
};

getKey<TestType>(test, "arrayKey"); // works
getKey<TestType>(test, "notArrayKey");
                     // ~~~~~~~~~~~~ --> Argument of type
// '"notArrayKey"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"arrayKey"'
```

I'm not sure though how to define the return type of function as `Array<number>`. Probably it's not possible because it cannot be guaranteed that `T` actually has a property of type `Array<number>`. But I'd love to be proved wrong!

Comment: Nice answer! Re: return type: I couldn't include all the info here in a comment, so I appended it to the end of my answer. I hope that's ok!